# Can't use db.entry in my repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, repository

Im using EF model in my project. Im using viewmodel in my controllers show data. However, I can't access db.entry in my repository. How come I can't access it?

This my repository

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MCT.ViewModels;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data;

namespace MCT.Models
{
    public class AdministrationRep
    {
        Model1Container _db = new Model1Container();

        public void changequstion(Question _question)
        {


        }
```

In my repository I'd like to use

```
db.entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Or is there another way to use edit for my controller?

Comment: Are you using `DbContext` API or `ObjectContext` API?

Comment: Why is your repository dependent on a view model? A repository should work only with domain models.

Comment: Im using ObjectContext for API

Comment: Darin: I've changed it to Question question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `ObjectContext` API you can change the state as follows

```
db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(model, EntityState.Modified);
```